# Options to return rows along with values for array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array called `$AgencyFeesBasicArray`:

```
Array ( 
  [AgencyFeesGetInfoResult] => Array ( 
    [FeeObject] => Array ( 
      [0] => Array ( 
        [PaymentID] => 816 
        [ClientID] => 1141 
        [ClientName] => Ortega, Daniel 
        [Account_ID] => 2222100000010717                                                         
        [State] => OK 
        [PaymentDate] => 2019-07-31T00:00:00 
        [Amount] => 8.0000 
        [CheckID] => 10 
        [CreditorName] => 0 
        [DRC_ClientID] => 1195 
        [DRC_TransactionID] => ) 
      [1] => Array ( 
        [PaymentID] => 817 
        [ClientID] => 1141 
        [ClientName] => Ortega, Daniel 
        [Account_ID] => 2222100000010717 
        [State] => OK 
        [PaymentDate] => 2019-07-31T00:00:00 
        [Amount] => 92.0000 
        [CheckID] => 11 
        [CreditorName] => MF 
        [DRC_ClientID] => 1195 
        [DRC_TransactionID] => ) 
      [2] => Array ( 
        [PaymentID] => 847 
        [ClientID] => 1141 
        [ClientName] => Ortega, Daniel 
        [Account_ID] => 2222100000010717 
        [State] => OK 
        [PaymentDate] => 2019-08-14T13:21:49.23 
        [Amount] => 195.0000 
        [CheckID] => 13 
        [CreditorName] => MF 
        [DRC_ClientID] => 1195 
        [DRC_TransactionID] => ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

It was brought over as stdClass and then converted to what is above with the json below:

```
$AgencyFeesBasicArray = json_decode(json_encode($soapResult), true);  
print_r($AgencyFeesBasicArray);
```

This recursive iterator returns the keys to values shown below:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($AgencyFeesBasicArray));
foreach($iterator as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value\n";echo '<br>';
}
```

Returns:

```
PaymentID => 816 
ClientID => 1141 
ClientName => Ortega, Daniel 
Account_ID => 2222100000010717 
State => OK 
PaymentDate => 2019-07-31T00:00:00 
Amount => 8.0000 
CheckID => 10 
CreditorName => 0 
DRC_ClientID => 1195 
DRC_TransactionID => 
PaymentID => 817 
ClientID => 1141 
ClientName => Ortega, Daniel 
Account_ID => 2222100000010717 
State => OK 
PaymentDate => 2019-07-31T00:00:00 
Amount => 92.0000 
CheckID => 11 
CreditorName => MF 
DRC_ClientID => 1195 
DRC_TransactionID => 
PaymentID => 847 
ClientID => 1141 
ClientName => Ortega, Daniel 
Account_ID => 2222100000010717 
State => OK 
PaymentDate => 2019-08-14T13:21:49.23 
Amount => 195.0000 
CheckID => 13 
CreditorName => MF 
DRC_ClientID => 1195 
DRC_TransactionID =>
```

… and that's great! Those are the values for the three records.

**My question is** : How do I loop through this to get the rows and the values together. What is above are the `key=>values` for the inner arrays (3 records) but there is no separation or indication of the record associated with each innre array [0], [1] or [2].

```
 [0]
        PaymentID => 816 
        ClientID => 1141 
        ClientName => Ortega, Daniel 
        Account_ID => 2222100000010717 
        State => OK 
        PaymentDate => 2019-07-31T00:00:00 
        Amount => 8.0000 
        CheckID => 10 
        CreditorName => 0 
        DRC_ClientID => 1195 
        DRC_TransactionID => 
    [1]
        PaymentID => 817 
        ClientID => 1141 
        ClientName => Ortega, Daniel 
        Account_ID => 2222100000010717 
        State => OK 
        PaymentDate => 2019-07-31T00:00:00 
        Amount => 92.0000 
        CheckID => 11 
        CreditorName => MF 
        DRC_ClientID => 1195 
        DRC_TransactionID => 
    [2]
        PaymentID => 847 
        ClientID => 1141 
        ClientName => Ortega, Daniel 
        Account_ID => 2222100000010717 
        State => OK 
        PaymentDate => 2019-08-14T13:21:49.23 
        Amount => 195.0000 
        CheckID => 13 
        CreditorName => MF 
        DRC_ClientID => 1195 
        DRC_TransactionID =>
```

THANKS FOR ANY HELP

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$AgencyFeesGetInfo['AgencyFeesGetInfoResult']['FeeObject'][]=array(
    "PaymentID"=>816,
    "ClientID"=>11414 
);
$AgencyFeesGetInfo['AgencyFeesGetInfoResult']['FeeObject'][]=array(
    "PaymentID"=>1212816,
    "ClientID"=>12111414 
);
$AgencyFeesGetAgencyFeesGetInfoInfoResult['AgencyFeesGetInfoResult']['FeeObject'][]=array(
    "PaymentID"=>832316,
    "ClientID"=>1112414 
);
$AgencyFeesGetInfo['AgencyFeesGetInfoResult']['FeeObject'][]=array(
    "PaymentID"=>812116,
    "ClientID"=>11212414 
); 
if($AgencyFeesGetInfo!=NULL)
{
    //this will give you desired output
    print_r($AgencyFeesGetInfo['AgencyFeesGetInfoResult']['FeeObject']);
     if($AgencyFeesGetInfo['AgencyFeesGetInfoResult']['FeeObject']!=NULL)
     {
          foreach($AgencyFeesGetInfo['AgencyFeesGetInfoResult']['FeeObject'] as $key=>$data)
          {
            print_r($data);
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: there was an extra row being printed using print_r ($data). Using print_r($key); removed the extra row and showed just what I was looking for thanks for your help Inventor Bala!